# DB2 Connection - Working from IBM DataStudio but failing from java Program

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2

I am trying to connect to DB2 Database from my windows machine using the JDBC Connection.

I am able to connect successfully using the same credentials from IBM Data Studio client but when i try the same from Java Program, i am getting the below exception.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.7.89] Exception java.net.ConnectException: Error opening socket to server lnx1iitmon05s/XXXXXX on port YYYY with message: Connection refused: connect. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:319)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:337)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.xb.a(xb.java:378)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.xb.<init>(xb.java:76)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.y(a.java:263)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:1786)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lb.a(lb.java:538)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.lb.<init>(lb.java:494)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:309)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:224)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.genericframework.db.RRDBConnection.getConnection(RRDBConnection.java:63)
    at com.genericframework.db.RRDBConnection.main(RRDBConnection.java:77)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.y.run(y.java:34)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.xb.a(xb.java:372)
    ... 12 more
```

Here is my code ..

```
 try {
            String filename = "com/genericframework/db/RRDBConnection.properties";
            //input = SPARKApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RRDBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RRDBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        dbHostName = prop.getProperty("DBHost");
        dbPort = prop.getProperty("DBPort");
        dbDatabasename = prop.getProperty("DBname");
        dbUsername = prop.getProperty("DBUserName");
        dbPassword = prop.getProperty("DBPassword");



        String connectionString = "jdbc:db2://"+dbHostName+":"+dbPort+"/"+dbDatabasename;

        System.out.println(connectionString);
        Connection  connection=null;
        try {
            //Class.forName( "COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver");
            Class.forName( "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,dbUsername,dbPassword);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RRDBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RRDBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try below Code:

```
        try{  
            Class.forName(className);  
            //System.out.println("class not found");  
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    dbURL,dbName,dbPassword);  
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 

            //your operations like select,insert or update

        catch(Exception e)  { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        finally {
            con.close(); 
        }
```

and add maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>licences</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!-- Adjust this properly -->
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!-- Adjust this properly -->
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

or use below jars:

```
1. db2jcc.jar 
2. db2jcc_license_cu.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the db2set DB2COMM command from the DB2 command window to start the TCP/IP connection:

db2set DB2COMM=protocol_names

For example, to set the database manager to start connection managers for the TCP/IP communication protocols, enter the following commands:

db2set DB2COMM=tcpip
db2stop
Db2start

Comment: i assume that we should enter these commands on DB Server. is this correct ?